# Induced Riemmanian metric and Differential of embedding

Tags: calculus, derivatives, smooth-manifolds

Suppose I have a manifold $M$ which is defined as the image of a 1-1 smooth map $G:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow H$ into a Hilbert space $H$.

I want to understand the Riemmanian metric on $M$ concretely, but in order to do so I need to understand $dG$.

How can I calculate this; that is how can I explicitly calculate dG?